# In C#, How to get the value of a variable when it changes Without threads or timers

Tags: c#

`int i = 0;`

When `i` value changes:

`i = (Atypical value)`

then

```
bool callback(int i)
   target = i;
   return true;
```

In C#, How to get the value of a variable when it changes Without using threads or timers

Comment: You can't. There is no inherent mechanism to alert when a variable changes. You have to explicitly code it to notify like using a property which raises an event, or the like.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a property:

```
private int _i = 0;
public int i
{
    get { return _i; }
    set
    {
        if (_i == value) { return; }
        _i = value;
        callback(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add might want to do a `if(value != _i)` before firing the callback, only if the OP wishes that only on change of the value and not set of the value.

Comment: @Nico Yep, well spotted.  Depends on what is required but the OP most likely meant that.

Comment: @LukePark - It would be nice to explain that this doesn't directly answer the OP's question. Is this case you've basically said to ignore checking if `_i` has changed, and watch `i` instead. This means that you can't just watch a variable, instead you have to wrap it in a class and add a property.

Comment: @Enigmativity I suppose.  I think it is safe to say that the above will achieve what the OP wanted to achieve though.  You are correct that we don't monitor the variable directly, but the above provides a solution that does **almost** the exact same thing.

Comment: @LukePark - I don't disagree that the OP probably will be able to use this, but you haven't given any explanation in your answer. I'm just suggesting that you do.

Comment: @Enigmativity By all means, please edit my answer to include the excerpt you think is necessary, I think you'll likely do a better job of it than I :)